# Split binary data from a separator

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a binary string of data like this:

```
trama = b'1 ; 12.0073 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n919.537 ; 1082.14 ; 0\r\n0 ; 850.26 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0 ; #\r\n1 ; 11.9612 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n933.792 ; 1097.16 ; 0\r\n0 ; 846.597 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0 ; #\r\n'
```

What I want is find the `#` separator because it means that at this point a set of data ends and consequently the following are another different sample.

I want this:

```
[
  ['1', '12.0073', 'NAN', 'NAN', '919.537', '1082.14', '0', '0', '850.26', 'NAN', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['1', '11.9612', 'NAN', 'NAN', '933.792', '1097.16', '0', '0', '846.597', 'NAN', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
]
```

Right now I'm doing all this process:

```
trama = b'1 ; 12.0073 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n919.537 ; 1082.14 ; 0\r\n0 ; 850.26 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0 ; #\r\n1 ; 11.9612 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n933.792 ; 1097.16 ; 0\r\n0 ; 846.597 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0 ; #\r\n'

values = [
    i.strip().decode() for i in trama.split()
    if i.strip().decode() not in [";"]
]


a, b = [], []
for i in values:
  if i != '#':
    b.append(i)
  else:
    a.append(b)
    b = []
```

It works, but I'm sure exists an easier way to do the same. Somebody knows a pythonic way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on the # first.

```py
trama = b'1 ; 12.0073 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n919.537 ; 1082.14 ; 0\r\n0 ; 850.26 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0 ; #\r\n1 ; 11.9612 ; NAN ; NAN\r\n933.792 ; 1097.16 ; 0\r\n0 ; 846.597 ; NAN\r\n0 ; 0 ; 0\r\n0 ; 0 ; #\r\n'

lines = trama.decode('UTF-8').split('#')

records = []

for line in lines:
    if not line.strip(): continue
    records.append([v.strip() for v in line.replace('\r\n', ';').split(';') if v.strip()])

for values in records:
    print(values)
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use `re`

Comment: Edited to remove `re`.

Answer (score 0):

@Lleims
Your question is not detailed enough but I will help you anyway.

I see 4 different separators:

- '#' : record separator
- '\r\n' : line separator (useless)
- ';' : item separator
- ' ' : spacer (useless)

I will assume that *trama* ends with '#\r\n' or '#' or '\r\n' but nothing else.
I also assume there are no space, '#' or '\r\n' inside item strings.

Here is the code:

```
    trama = b'...'    
    s = trama.decode().replace( '\r\n', '').replace( ';', '').rstrip( '#')    
    records = []    
    recs = s.split( '#') # get a list of records    
    for rec in recs: records.append( rec.split()) # get a list of lists
```